# set href value in Lightbox Dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var Href = 'http://www.apple.com';
            $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function () {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href: Href,
                    type: 'iframe',
                    padding: 5
                });
            });

        });

    <ul>
        <li><a id="fancybox-manual-b" href="javascript:;">Open Window</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I need to get the 'Href' value from a textbox and when ever someone puts a website in the textbox it should get that instead of apple.com

Comment: Just a note, I probably wouldn't name the variable `Href` and I would pay more attention to your scope.

Comment: @Sethen :if i could get an answer that would be great .Sir !

Comment: @Fahad Try renaming your variable and move it into the click function.  Have no answers provided below have solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some html like:

```
<input type="text" id="target">
```

Then you can use jQuery's [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to get the value of the textbox by its `id`:

```
var href = $('#target').val();
```

Which you'll obviously need to do every time someone clicks your fancybox link, so that you get the most up to date value from the textbox:

```
$(function () {
    $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function () {
        var href = $('#target').val();
        $.fancybox.open({
            href: href,
            type: 'iframe',
            padding: 5
        });
    });
});
```

It's worth noting that if a user puts some text in the input that doesn't resolve to an existing url you're going to get an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
     $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function () {
          $.fancybox.open({
              href: $("#yourTextBoxId").val(), // Your textboxId here
              type: 'iframe',
              padding: 5
          });
     });

});
```

Make sure that you out your text-boxes id in place of `yourTextBoxId`